# How do I parse HTML using php?

Tags: php, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

i have html file like

```
<table class="example2" >
<td >15-06-2012</td>
 <td >154</td>
    <td >1.34</td>
    <td >60</td>
   <td >25</td>
    <td >15</td>
 <td >Doctors service, Nursing service, Auxiliary Service</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Actually these value are from data base. And may be more than 200. 
I want to use pasing html. As i am new to parsing please give me one example to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML can be quite a chore...  Since HTML is primarily a presentation markup language, the syntax makes data extraction a bit of a challenge.  Tags may not be well-balanced, a tag like `<b>` doesn't really provide data context, etc.

Your best bet is to use an existing library, such as [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).